# Placing value in text field using datepicker and sending to function

Tags: jquery

How can I keep the value of the datepicker in the text area while using a function?

ex:

```
if($currentSelectionClass == "rowStartDate"){
    $('<input id="selectDateStart" type="text" />')
        .attr('name', 'editStartDate')
        .addClass('editStartDate')
        .appendTo(this)
        .datepicker({onSelect: startDateSubmit()});
    }
```

AND how would I send the datepicker value to my function?

Function code:

```
function startDateSubmit(){
            $selectDateStart = $('#selectDateStart').val();
            $.ajax({ 
                url: '/ajax/training-update.php',
                data: {action: $selectDateStart},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(output) {
                    alert(output);
                    }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to specify reference to a function, not to call the function

   ```
   .datepicker({onSelect: startDateSubmit});
   ```
2. You need to add argument to your function declaration

   ```
   function startDateSubmit(selectedDate) {
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Only one thing is missing. This is acting on multiple date fields. It fills in the value of the first selected date. However, it doesn't for the rest. The values are passed to the function, it just doesn't populate the text field.

Comment: @Paul: I'm not sure I understand the current problem :-(

Comment: Sorry. I have a table listing classes, their start dates end dates, etc. When the startDate is clicked, it triggers a datepicker. There are 50+ dates on the page. When I select the first date, it populates the text field and triggers the function. So far so good. However, when I click on another start date and pick a date from the datepicker, the value isn't populated in the text field. It submits the correct date via AJAX, it just doesn't display in the text field. Hopefully that makes sense. :)

Comment: @Paul: update your question with the actual correspondent code

Comment: I've decided to approach this a little differently and what I just mentioned is no longer an issue. Thanks for your help on the other stuff, it helped!